# Cordova: screen not rotating

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, screen-rotation

I have a problem with Cordova. When I compile my test app and test it on my device, the screen in WP8 does not rotate; and I suspect that it does not rotate in Android or iOS either. I have added the preference Orientation "default" explicitly.

Also it does not work if I leave that preference out. I can say for sure that it does not rotate on Android nor iOS if I leave the preference Orientation "default" out.

I am not sure what the reason is. There are so many versions of cordova with incompatible preference definitions that I thought I'd ask here.

My Cordova Version:

```
cordova -version
5.0.0
```

My installed plugins:

```
cordova plugins list
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
```

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="de.test.alexander.myapp" version="1.0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>
        My phonegap test app
    </description>
    <author email="alexander@gmail" href="http://localhost/">
        Alexander
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="internet" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />

    <access origin="*" />

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
    <icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

    <icon src="ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <gap:splash src="Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

    <gap:splash src="land-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="land-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="land-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="land-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="port-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="port-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="port-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="port-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />

    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon src="ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
        <!-- tile image -->
        <icon src="Background.png" width="159" height="159" />  
        <splash src="SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="768" height="1280"/>
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: I don't use the config.xml in the root, but have you tested to remove the preference in it and just set the orientation in Xcode under general settings?

Comment: @Joerg We want to automate, because we forgot it once and delivered a broken app to the store. I have written a vbscript to set the preference in the MainPage.xaml; and I would also have to write scripts to set the preference in android and iOS. I would expect cordova to have such a thing already builtin and would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a view to the newest config.xml doc at

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/config_ref/index.html

For Android devices you need:

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="Orientation" value="sensorLandscape" />
</platform>
```

and for iOS:

```
<platform name="ios">
        <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
</platform>
```

and BlackBerry:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

But there is no doc about Windows.

Comment: The docs state that *Possible values are **default**, landscape or portrait. Example: **<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />** .* and no restriction to certain platforms. I would expect my code to work then, but it doesn't. Possibly because I use 5.0.0, not 5.4.0?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. It also can be, that it depends on the Xcode version. Have you thought about to use a precompile script  in the SDK? There you can also manipulate files.

Comment: In the 5.0.0 docs I found "The default value means Cordova will strip the orientation preference entry from the platform's manifest/configuration file allowing the platform to fallback to its default behavior.". It seems that the default behaviour for iOS and WP8 is portrait-only, and there is no platform-independent switch that sets the behaviour on all platforms to "both portrait and landscape".

Comment: Thx for clarification. I'm a listener in the cordova dev list and will make a note there.